# Left side markdown diff outside of its area

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, design, diff

This is how I see [this review](https://vi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1519) on Chrome:

[image]

[image]

It seems removal of spaces went outside of its area from the left side and looks like something was removed on the right side.

This is very confusing way to see what was actually change, unless you go to the rendered output.

Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2873468/revisions).

Comment: Repro on Chromium 44.0.2403.89; no repro on Firefox 40.0.3.

Comment: Very curiously, adding `span.diff-delete { white-space: pre }` seems to fix this bug on Chromium, but *triggers it* (as, indeed, one would expect) on Firefox. I'm inclined to call this a Chrome bug.

Comment: Still reproducible on Chrome 72.0.3626.121. :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is a Chrome bug.  In fact, I suspect it's related to [this longstanding bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35443), as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316098/prevent-inline-block-from-wrapping-on-white-space-pre).

Anyway, the answer by Han in that thread suggested a possible work-wround using `:after` pseudo-elements.  I've tested it, and the following CSS hack seems to (more or less) fix the rendering:

```css
/* kluge to avoid Chrome pre-wrap bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266258 */
.full-diff .diff-delete:after, .full-diff .diff-add:after {
    content: '';
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

(The `font-size: 0px` seems to be necessary; I have no idea why, but removing it makes the hack not work.  In any case, we're dealing with a buggy rendering engine here, so there's no reason why any of this should necessarily make sense.)

The CSS hack described above should be safe and have no visible effect on other browsers, since the pseudo-elements it adds are completely empty.  I have tested this on Firefox and confirmed that, indeed, there appears to be no visible difference with or without the hack.

And yes, this is going into the next release of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup).